# Response always comes null in jquery ajax response

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have run ajax in jquery.

```
$('#subsubcategorymain').on("change",function(){
    var maincategory_id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"{{route('categories.dynamicdropdown')}}",
        type:"get",
        data:{id:maincategory_id},
        success: function(res)
        {
            alert(res);
        }
    });
});
```

route

```
Route::get('categories/dynamicdropdown','cateogory\AdminCategoryController@dynamicdropdown')->name('categories.dynamicdropdown');
```

controller

```
public function dynamicdropdown(Request $request)
    {
        return response([
            'ok'
        ]);
    }
```

but response always comes nothing (empty). Never happened before.
Is it because of the resource feature i am using in controller??
--resource?

Comment: Is it because of the resource features that controller provides boiler plate? I have made extra function "dynamicdrowdown()"? Is it because of this?

Answer (score 1):

```
return response()->json("ok");
```